# How do I enable more debugging for MAAS installs?

Tags: maas

I'm currently having trouble installing the daily Wily release (it's failing). I'm only able to get:

initctl: Unknown job: lldpd
stop: Unknown instance:

I'd like to get more/better debug output during the install to help identify what exactly is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using MAAS and the curtin installer (which is the default since [release 1.7](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/11/20/maas-1-7-one-maas-multiple-operating-systems/)) a node install happens in the following set of steps:

1. The node PXE boots into an ephemeral environment using the version of Ubuntu you selected to install.
2. cloud-init downloads user data from MAAS, including ssh keys and curtin.
3. cloud-init sets up the ssh keys and starts curtin installing the node.
4. curtin finishes installing and reboots the node.

It looks like step 1 is working for you. To debug steps 2 and beyond you need to capture the console output from the node while it boots. If you are actually deploying a VM (as opposed to bare metal), that's easy -- just access the output from the host. For the bare metal cases, you will need to use remote KVM or serial over LAN functionality to capture the console output. The console output will contain cloud-init log messages that indicate how it's progressing. It can fail in various ways so you'll need to dig further into whatever you see there.

If you don't have a way to grab the console remotely, one way to dig further into failures as this stage is to backdoor the ephemeral install image with a user/password that will allow you to login via the console or via ssh. Here's how that's done:

- First, disable image syncing on the settings page of your MAAS server. This prevents MAAS from overwriting the backdoored images.
- Then, this script can be used to setup the backdoors on all of the images in the server.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --assume-yes bzr
  bzr branch lp:~maas-maintainers/maas/backdoor-image backdoor-image

  imgs=$(echo /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/*/*/*/*/*/*/root-image)
  for img in $imgs; do
      [ -f "$img.dist" ] || sudo cp -a --sparse=always $img $img.dist
  done

  cd backdoor-image
  for img in $imgs; do
      sudo ./backdoor-image -v --user=backdoor --password-auth --password=ubuntu $img
  done
  ```
- Now, retry the installation of the node. Once the node starts ssh you should be able to login with user 'backdoor' and password 'ubuntu'. If SSH never starts, you can login on the console with the same user and password. Once logged in you can use 'sudo' to debug.
- Once you have figured out the problem and addressed it, be sure to re-enable image synchronization, and replace the backdoored images with stock ones:

  ```
  imgs=$(echo /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/*/*/*/*/*/*/root-image)
  for img in $imgs; do
      [ -f "$img.dist" ] && sudo mv -f $img.dist $img
  done
  ```

Even without the backdoor there is a window of time during which you can ssh in, as during installation cloud-init sets up ssh keys and starts sshd. Once  ssh keys are in place, curtin starts installing; at this point you can ssh  into the system using the 'ubuntu' user and the ssh key for your MAAS user.  You must do this quickly, before curtin finishes and reboots the system. To prevent curtin from powering off the node, run

```
touch /tmp/block-poweroff
```

as soon as you are logged in. You can do this in a while loop to avoid needing to get the timing exactly right; this should to be run as soon as you trigger the installation:

```
while true; do ssh node-foo.maas touch /tmp/block-poweroff && break; done
```

At that point you should be able to ssh in normally without worrying about curtin powering the node off.

Whichever way you logged into the system, remember you can use `sudo` as the `ubuntu` user; this lets you, for instance, access all the logs on the system.